# AI Development MNIST's numbers are all misrecognized

Tags: mnist

You have entered the code as shown below.

If I write numbers on paper with my handwriting and take a picture, and put in a large image without adjusting the size of the image, it all says 8, and if I reduce the image to 28*28, it all says 1. Why is that? ^^

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image  # 이미지 처리를 위한 라이브러리

# 난수 시드 설정
seed = 0
np.random.seed(seed)
tf.random.set_seed(3)

# MNIST 데이터셋 불러오기
(x_train, y_class_train), (x_test, y_class_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
print('학습셋 이미지수: {}'.format(x_train.shape[0]))
print('테스트셋 이미지수: {}'.format(x_test.shape[0]))

# 이미지 전처리
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32') / 255

y_class_train = pd.get_dummies(y_class_train)
y_class_test = pd.get_dummies(y_class_test)

# 모델 정의 및 컴파일
x = tf.keras.layers.Input([28, 28, 1])
h = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(6, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='swish')(x)
h = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=5, activation='swish')(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.Dense(120, activation='swish')(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.Dense(84, activation='swish')(h)
h = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(h)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(h)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(x, y)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
early_stopping_callbacks = EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=10)

# 모델 학습
model.fit(x_train, y_class_train, epochs=100, batch_size=200, callbacks=[early_stopping_callbacks])
model.summary()

# 손글씨 이미지를 불러오고 예측 수행
image_path = '28_2.png'  # 이미지 파일 경로 지정
image = Image.open(image_path).convert('L')
image = image.resize((28, 28))
image_array = np.array(image)
image_array = image_array.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1).astype('float32') / 255.0

predicted_probabilities = model.predict(image_array)
predicted_number = np.argmax(predicted_probabilities)

print(f"내가 쓴 숫자는: {predicted_number}")

model.save('my_model.h5')
```